# sigc::mem_fun and pass params from a class method

Tags: c++, class, methods, gtkmm, libsigc++

In gtkmm I can use something like this in the constructor:

```
// Gtk::ImageMenuItem *iQuit;
iQuit->signal_activate().connect (sigc::mem_fun (*this, &FormUI::on_quit_activated) );
```

But I'd like to use a method to set item's properties, for example:

```
void FormUI::SetItemProps (Gtk::ImageMenuItem *i, const Glib::ustring& _l, ?what should I put here?)
{
i->set_use_stock (true);
i->set_label (_l);
i->signal_activate().connect (sigc::mem_fun (*this, ???) ); <-- what to pass there
}
```

so I can use something like this in the constructor:

```
SetItemProps (iQuit, "gtk-quit", &FormUI::on_quit_activated);
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may like in this using typedef:

```
typedef void (FormUI::*function_ptr)();
void FormUI::SetItemProps (Gtk::ImageMenuItem *i, const Glib::ustring& _l, function_ptr fun)
{
    i->set_use_stock (true);
    i->set_label (_l);
    i->signal_activate().connect (sigc::mem_fun (*this, fun) );
}
```

And the method on_quit_activated() has to be as declared type.

To call, use

```
SetItemProps (iQuit, "gtk-quit", &FormUI::on_quit_activated);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use sigc::bind():
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-binding-extra-arguments.html.en